# Vue3js Cutom input component disappearing if value=null

Tags: vue.js

I’m using the following component for custom clic-edit input

```
<template>
  <el-input
    v-show="edit"
    ref="inputField"
    type="text"
    placeholder="place"
    v-model='value'
    @blur.native="
      local = $event.target.value;
      edit = false;
      $emit('input', local);
    "
    @keyup.enter.native="
      local = $event.target.value;
      edit = false;
      $emit('input', local);"
  />

  <span v-show="!edit" @click="startEdit" >  {{ local }}</span>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value"],

  data() {
    return {
      edit: false,
      local: this.value,
    };
  },

  watch: {
    value: function () {
      this.local = this.value;
    },
  },

  methods: {
    startEdit() {
      this.edit = true;
      this.$refs.inputField.focus();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I am then using it, everything's seems ok.
Text switch to input as expected.
But If I pass a null value then the rendered component disappears.
Why ? How can I avoid this ?

```
<template>
      <ClickEdit :value="'velue-test '" />
</template>
```

When passing or validating an empty value, the component disappears.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/1-vue3js-jo716?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue

Answer (score 0):

Actually your components is being rendered (you can see in devtools console). But because you pass empty or null as `value` prop to component there is nothing to show for editing. So you must set a default text to show in case of empty value (for example `Edit here...`). Then after user update the input replace it.

You can see this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1-vue3js-forked-zq94c?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue) to understand what I mean.